# White stuff in lemon tree branches?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, fruit-trees, lemons

The stuff literally looks like white paint drops that fell on the plant. it’s all over the plant and it’s not paint.

What is it and what can I do to get rid of it?

Is it contagious?

Thanks.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The photos are not 100% on focus. Could you take one, and check if it looks like a contact lens (so a scale insect), or if it has "roots" (so a fungus). To me it seems more like the first, but on second photo.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say a scale bug.  Do you have ants on the tree?  They might be farming the scale bugs for their honey secretions.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It doesn’t have roots (I can scrape it off) and there are no ants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure looks like scale to me ; there are various kinds, my problem scale is smooth and dark. I remove mine with a finger nail but you have a lot. A dilute oil spray should work but avoid getting much oil on leaves. Oil sprays are usually used when the plant is dormant , but I have had to use oil ,sparingly , on growing camellias.  You can buy "dormant oil" in a garden shop or, read the instructions in the garden shop and get much cheaper baby oil or mineral oil ( they all come out of the same refinery unit) . "Dormant oil" has a tiny bit of surfactant , a.k.a. detergent. So .I add a drop or 2 of liquid detergent to a gallon of water/oil  mix.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I literally scraped all that crap off the plant.

Comment: What do you me when the plant is dormant?

Comment: Dormant means no leaves but I guess lemons do not go dormant,